Integration with FLASK (Python) And Laravel -- API
I'm attempting to establish an API connection between Python Flask and Laravel, but I consistently receive a 503 error.
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class TesteController extends Controller{

public function enviar(Request $request){
    return view('teste');
}

public function teste(Request $request){
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost:5000']);

    $response = $client->request('POST', '/api/usuarios', [
        'json' => [
            'nome' => 'João',
            'email' => 'joao@example.com',
        ]
    ]);
}

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/usuarios', methods=['POST'])
def criar_usuario():
    novo_usuario = request.json
    return jsonify({'mensagem': 'Usuário criado com sucesso'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


I've tried doing everything, changing the port, and I don't know what to do; it always gives the same error 503 || Server error: GET http://localhost:5000/api/usuarios resulted in a 503 Service Unavailable response:   <meta http-equiv (truncated...)

Both fail? How do you serve http://localhost:5000?

I'm hosting on 5000 from Flask itself and on 8000 from Laravel itself (php artisan serve)

In your code, your route "/api/usuarios" is a POST but you seem to be trying to use a GET when doing the request. To use the route "/api/usuarios" as your code is now, you need to use:

POST http://localhost:5000/api/usuarios

and afterward whatever JSON infos you need to send.
If you actually just want to get the message without sending something, change

methods=[POST]

to

methods=[GET]

in your @app.route
